# How not to jam ruby threading when using OSX Cocoa FFI?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, macos, cocoa, ffi

While tracking down threading issues in desktop application development I have isolated one of multiple threading issues Id like to get out of the way to hopefully mature the world to a point where real application development in ruby is even remotely possible.

And this particular case ended up being quite simple to illustrate, yet I could really use input on how to solve it.

I seems that NSApplication run breaks the thread mechanisms in ruby.
And the question is simply - how to avoid this?

The following outputs:

```
ping
ping
and thats the end of ruby threading - no more pings, goodbye!!
```

Then no more..

```
require 'ffi'

module ObjC
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib 'objc'

  attach_function :sel_registerName, [:string], :pointer
  attach_function :objc_msgSend, [:pointer, :pointer, :varargs], :pointer
  def self.msgSend( id, selector, *args )
    selector = sel_registerName(selector) if selector.is_a? String
    return objc_msgSend( id, selector, *args )
  end
  attach_function :objc_getClass, [:string], :pointer
end

module Cocoa
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib '/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa'

  attach_function :NSApplicationLoad, [], :bool
  NSApplicationLoad()
 end

pool = ObjC.msgSend(ObjC.msgSend(ObjC.objc_getClass("NSAutoreleasePool"),"alloc"),"init")
application = ObjC.msgSend(ObjC.objc_getClass("NSApplication"),"sharedApplication")

Thread.new do
  loop do
    sleep 1
    puts "ping"
  end
end

sleep 3

puts "and thats the end of ruby threading - no more pings, goodbye!!"

ObjC.msgSend(application,"run")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on yet, but it appears to keep pinging if you call `#join` on the Thread.

Comment: Silly me. `#join` makes it suspend the calling thread (here, the main thread), and keep running the pinging thread indefinitely until it exits (which it never will).

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with the GIL, but adding `, blocking: true` to the `attach_function`s doesn't seem to help.